# stripe form not showing when billing name has an apostrophe

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I have the following stripe payment form on my page:

```
stripe.createToken(card,{name: '<?php echo $order->customer['firstname'] . ' ' . $order->customer['lastname']; ?>', address_line1 : '<?php echo $order->customer['street_address']; ?>', address_city : '<?php echo $order->customer['city']; ?>', address_state : '<?php echo $order->customer['state']; ?>', address_country : '<?php echo $order->customer['country']['title']; ?>' }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            // Inform the user if there was an error
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
            // Send the token to your server
            stripeTokenHandler(form, result.token);
        }
    });
});
```

I recenetly found out that a customer with the last name o'brian was not being shown the portion of the form that allows them to enter the credit card info. It took a while to find out why they were having that issue.

In any case, should I just be removing the apostrophe with a str_replace? That seems a bit strange to have to remove the apostrophe? Or is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophe matches the single quote that starts the JavaScript string, and ends the string, causing unmatched quotes in the JavaScript.

Use `json_encode()` to safely translate a PHP value into the equivalent JavaScript literal, rather than echoing the raw value inside quotes.

```
stripe.createToken(card,{
    name: <?php echo json_encode($order->customer['firstname'] . ' ' . $order->customer['lastname']); ?>, 
    address_line1 : <?php echo json_encode($order->customer['street_address']); ?>,
    address_city : <?php echo json_encode($order->customer['city']); ?>, 
    address_state : <?php echo json_encode($order->customer['state']); ?>, 
    address_country : <?php echo json_encode($order->customer['country']['title']); ?> 
}).then(function(result) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough to use double quotes instead of apostrophes to enclose strings?

Something like:

```
stripe.createToken(card,{name: "<?php echo $order->customer["firstname"] . ' ' . $order->customer["lastname"]; ?>"
```